# Convert part of cell array containing all strings to doubles

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I have a cell array with 9 columns where each cell contains strings, but only the 9th column is actually a string, the first 8 are supposed to be numbers. Is there a way to convert each cell in the first 8 columns of a cell array from a cell containing a string, to a cell containing a double?

Comment: sorry! totally forgot

Comment: No problem! We tend to forget those things but it's best so that the thread is closed and the answers are available for future readers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! It's quite easy with a for loop or using cellfun:

**1:Loop**
1) Let's create a cell array containing strings:

```
CellA = sprintfc('%d',1:9) %// Nice function to populate cell array with strings

CellA = 

    '1'    '2'    '3'    '4'    '5'    '6'    '7'    '8'   '9'
```

2) Loop:

```
for k = 1:size(CellA,2)-1

    CellA{:,k} = str2double(CellA{:,k});

end

CellA %// Display the content of CellA

CellA = 

    [1]    [2]    [3]    [4]    [5]    [6]    [7]    [8]   '9'
```

**2: Cellfun**

```
CellB = [cellfun(@str2double,CellA(1:end-1),'UniformOutput',false) CellA(end)]
```

In this case you apply str2double to all but the last elements of the cell array and then you concatenate them with the last element of CellA, i.e. the string. Both outputs are similar.

Et voilà :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the str2num function on each element of the cell in the first 8 columns to convert the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without loops: use [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to convert from cell array of strings to numeric array, and then [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to convert from numeric array to cell array of numbers:

```
myCell(:,1:8) = num2cell(str2double(myCell(:,1:8)));
```